# YoutubeService throwing Verify Error

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am getting an error while trying to init a YouTubeService object

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/gdata/client/media/MediaService
```

here is the init

```
 YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(Keys.youtubeApplicationName,
                Keys.youtubeDeveloperID);
```